# BFS algorithm in Python (return list with distances to other nodes)

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I have a problem such that I need to implement a BFS method and return a list with the distances to other nodes, given the start node and an adjancecy matrix, as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

example.matrix = np.matrix('0 1 0 1; 1 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 1; 1 0 1 0')

def BFS(adjMatrix, startNode):
         # Node count, assume rows = columns in matrix
         nodeCount = adjMatrix.shape[0]
         # Define node candidate lists
         nextDepthCandidates = []

         candidates= [startNode]
         .....

return result
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried? What issues are you facing with your current implementation?

Comment: Can this be a variation of [Kruskal's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm)?

Comment: @Jacq Not exactly. Minimum Spanning Tree is different from doing a BFS.

Comment: My question is really how to solve it. I have no idea how to do it. Could you help me pls?